# Approach to test convergence of $\int_1^\infty \frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{x^2} dx$

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

The following improper integral converges:
$\int_1^\infty \frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{x^2} dx$

This integral CAN be evaluated, however is there a simpler way to test for convergence/divergence without evaluating it? I tried to use the comparison test, but could not come up with a suitable function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comparison test as follows

$$\int_1^\infty \frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{x^2} dx<
\int_1^\infty \frac{\sqrt{2x}}{x^2} dx=\sqrt2 
 \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^{3/2}} dx=2\sqrt2
$$

Comment: Thanks @Quanto. How did you decide on the other integral to compare against? I see that the other answers are also targeting $\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^\frac{3}{2}} dx$

Comment: @mpny1 - the comparison function follows naturally after the inequality $\sqrt{x+1} < \sqrt{2x}$ for $x>1$

Answer (score 2):

Since$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{x^2}}{x^{-3/2}}=1$$and since $\displaystyle\int_1^\infty x^{-3/2}\,\mathrm dx$ converges, then so does your integral.

Comment: Why on earth was this answer down voted??

Comment: @MarkViola Because it was posted by me, I guess. It happens a lot. Several similar questions are posted more or less at the same time, and only mine gets downvoted.

Comment: I have had the same experience.  I suspect there are users who target specific people.  Here is a (+1) to neutralize the offender.

Comment: Thank you. That was nice of you.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

The $x\approx1$ region has a finite integrand; for $x\gg1$, the integrand is asymptotic to $x^{-3/2}$.